# How to handle frequently changing row in recycler view in anroid

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter, android-listadapter

I am working on a tool that list devices based on certain value and the signal of the device is one of them and its defined by RSSI value [rssi](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-does-rssi-dbm-relate-to-signal-quality-percent-439)
Here this(RSSI) value changes frequently which keeps updating the rows in the recycler view.  I have just started with recycler view and by looking internet I am using a list adapter with diffutil callback. But it behave the same here is example behaviour

https://youtube.com/shorts/UNqj_6wwFnI?feature=share

I want only signal element of the whole view to be updated, not the whole row gets shuffled which makes very hard user to select a device when number of devices are large.

My diffutil impl

```
private val diffUtil = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<A>() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(
    oldItem: A,
    newItem: A
): Boolean {
    return oldItem.id == newItem.id
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(
    oldItem: A,
    newItem: A
): Boolean {

    return oldItem == newItem
}
```

Equal impl

```
   override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass){
        return false
    }

    other as A

    return (id == other.id
            && name == other.name
            && address == other.address
            && selected == other.selected
            && version == other.version
            && rssi == other.rssi
            && stateOfCharge == other.stateOfCharge
            && configVersionNumber == other.configVersionNumber
            && expanded == other.expanded)

}
```

The data A fields

```
 var id: Long = 0,
var name: String = "",
var address: String = "",
var selected: Boolean = false,
var version: String = Version().formattedVersion,
var voltage: Float = 0f,
var rssi: Int = 0,
var stateOfCharge: Int = 0,
var configVersionNumber: Int = 0,
var timestamp: Long = 0,
var expanded: Boolean = false
```

Comment: You need to maintain your list ordering somehow, e.g. when you get new data for a device that's already in the old list, instead of moving it to the front of the new list, place it where the original data was in the old list. Exactly how you'd do that depends on how you're generating these lists in the first place, but things are moving around in the `RecyclerView` because they're moving around in the lists you're providing to it

Comment: @cactustictacs Thanks it worked after sorting by a specific field